# Proof with curve smoothness.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I've got 2 problems.

1. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ $:$ $Im f = f(\mathbb{R}) = \{|x|+|y|=1\}$. Show that $ \exists_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ : $f'(t)=(0,0)$

2.$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ of $C^1$ class. If $f'(t_0) \neq 0$ then $C = Im F$ in neighbourhood of $x_0=f(t_0)$ is smooth $C^1$ curve.

My idea  for 1.

$$
f(t+2\pi n)=f(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
({cos}^2t,{sin}^2t) & \textrm{when $0\le t\le \frac{\pi}{2}$}\\
(-{cos}^2t,{sin}^2t) & \textrm{when $\frac{\pi}{2} \le t \le \pi$}\\
(-{cos}^2t,-{sin}^2t) & \textrm{when $ \pi \le t \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$}\\
({cos}^2t,-{sin}^2t) & \textrm{when $ \frac{3\pi}{2} \le t \le 2\pi$}
\end{array} \right.
$$

I don't have any idea about 2nd.

Comment: I think you condition should be $f'(0)=(0,0)$ or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and $f:M$ to $N$ be a map. Then $f$ is called an immersion if its derivative is everywhere injective.

In your case $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $N=\mathbb{R}^{3}$. The fact that $\frac{df}{dt}_{t_{0}}\neq 0$ and that  $\frac{df}{dt}$ is continuous implies we can find a neighbourhood of $f(t_{o})$ such that kernel of $d_{f}$ is zero and hence the map $d_{f}$ is injective. This cna be seen by using the range-kernel theorem.

Then the map $f$ is an immersion locally and that implies $f(t)$ is locally a manifold of dimension 1 which is by definition a curve.